# How do I break out of a While loop when either the variable becomes True/False or a certain amount of times?

Tags: python

```
import sys

ok = True
count = 0
while ok == True:
    try:
        a = int(input("What is a? Put number pls "))
        ok = False
        count = count + 1
    except ValueError:
        print("no u")

if (count >= 3):
    sys.exit()
```

What I'm trying to do here is get the user to input an integer. If the user inputted an integer or the loop has ran 3 times, the program stops. I have tried putting the if statement both in the try and except statements, it still keeps on looping.

I have also tried this:

```
ok = True
count = 0
while ok == True:
    try:
        a = int(input("What is a? Put number pls "))
        ok = False
        count = count + 1
    except ValueError:
        print("no u")
    if (count >= 3):
        break
```

It still doesn't break out of the loop.

I have inputted numbers, breaks out of the loop as what I expected. I then tried to input random letters and hoped that the loop stops after 3 times, it still continues to loop until I have inputted a number. Happens to both versions.

Comment: `count` only increments when there is not an exception two lines above it. This is one of the reasons you put as little code as possible in a  `try` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach which you might not have thought of:

```
count = 0
while count < 3:
    try:
        a = int(input("What is a? Put number pls "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("no u")
        count = count + 1
```

There is no need for `ok` because you can just use a `break` statement if you want to end the loop. What you really want to be testing for is if `count` is less than three, and incrementing `count` every time the user gets it wrong.

There is no reason to increment `count` if the loop is about to end, so you want to increment `count` whenever there is a `ValueError` (in the except-block) and the loop is about to start again.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a slightly expanded version of michaels solution, that takes advantage of the `while/else` mechanism to determine when no good input was provided

```
count = 0
while count < 3:
    try:
        a = int(input("What is a? Put number pls "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("no u")
        count = count + 1
else: # is triggered if the loop completes without a break
   print("No Break... used up all tries with bad inputs")
   sys.exit(-1)

print(f"You entered a number {a}")
```